# JPA on GAE: find does not return records but datastore has few records

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have one-to-many owned relationship. Here is my parent class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
public class Strip {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key key;

private long id;
private String filename = "";

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "strip", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Quote> quotes = new ArrayList<Quote>();

public long getId() {
    return key.getId(); 
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
}
public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

public List<Quote> getQuotes() {
    return quotes;
}

public void setQuotes(List<Quote> quotes) {
    this.quotes = quotes;
}

public Key getKey() {
    return key;
}
}
```

And child class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
public class Quote {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key key;

private long id;

private String quote = "";

@ManyToOne
private Strip strip;

public long getId() {
    return key.getId();
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getQuote() {
    return quote;
}

public void setQuote(String quote) {
    this.quote = quote;
}

@XmlTransient
public Strip getStrip() {
    return strip;
}

public void setStrip(Strip strip) {
    this.strip = strip;
}

}
```

And there is method for adding Quote in Strip:

```
public JResponse<StripResult> putStripWithQuote(@PathParam("strip_id") long id,                                                     Quote quote) {
    StripResult result = new StripResult();
    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    Strip strip = null;

    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        strip = em.find(Strip.class, id);
        if (strip == null) {
            result.setCode("0");
            result.setMessage("Strip is not found.");
        } else {
            strip.getQuotes().add(quote);
        }

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result.setCode("0");
        result.setMessage("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        em.close();
    }

    result.setStrip(strip);
    return JResponse.ok(result).build();
}
```

After executing this method I can see in the Datastore Viewer that I have updated existing Strip entity and new Quote entity.

Even if I query all quotes everything work fine, I able to see all quotes.

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select from " + Quote.class.getName());
list = new ArrayList<Quote>(q.getResultList());
```

mMy problem: The `entityManager.find(Quote.class, "id of existing quote")` does not return anything.

What am I doing wrong or missing here? Is it something wrong with persistence context?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Quote` entity, the primary key defined `@Id` is the `key` variable, not the `id` variable. Is it this value you are using in your

```
em.find(Quote.class,"key of existing quote");
```

?

Comment: I mean in your query for a Quote object, the id to look for is the `key` column from the DB, not the `id` column. Or you need to move the `@Id` above the `long id;` line.

Comment: If I move @Id to long id I will have following error: Unsupported primary key type: long

Comment: as a second parameter for find function I use key.getId() value, this id I send to client with json and client send it back to server

Comment: If you use `key.getId()` then your `@Id` was fine. If you wanted (for other reason) make the `long id` an Id, you just need to make it a `Long id` object, not primitive `long`. I might delete this whole answer as it doesn't fix your initial issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

- Query by Key

`TypedQuery<Strip> query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Strips WHERE s.key = ?1",Strip.class);
strip =  query.setParameter(1, key).getSingleResult();`

- Query by ID

`TypedQuery<Strip> query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Strips WHERE s.id=?1",Strip.class);
strip =  query.setParameter(1, id).getSingleResult();`

- Query all Quotes Owned by a Parent Strip

`TypedQuery<Strip>query=em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Strips WHERE s.Strip=1",Strip.class);
List<Strip> strip = query.getResultList();`

- Query ALL QOUTES in your DB

`Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Quote s, Quote.class");
 List<Quote> ALLQuotes= query.getResultList();`